# how to capture output from screen command in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

When I use the unix screen command to open a screen and I run a unix command (say ls), the text at the top disappears and I can only see what comes at the end of the output. How can I capture the complete output in the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Screen capabilities:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>escape</kbd> and you'll be able to move your cursor as in regular text editors